# Is it possible to name sub-patterns in regular expressions and then extract matches by the sub-pattern names in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Is it possible to name sub-patterns in regular expressions and then extract matches by the sub-pattern names in C++?

For example can I have regex like this: text bla bla PLACE delimiter bla bla TIME

and then match that regex to a string, and if it matches, then to be able to do:

```
smatch sm;
sm[PLACE] or sm[TIME]
```

Edit: from what I understood this is not available in the standard regex in C++11,
      but boost regex has this feature.

Another question I have is, what if PLACE has more than one match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called *Named Capture Groups*, they're described here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

They're only supported by some regular expression engines. C++ isn't mentioned specifically, but if it uses PCRE 7.2 or later it should support them. If your regexp engine doesn't support them, you'll have to stick with traditional numbered capture groups.

Comment: What do you mean by traditional numbered capture groups?

Comment: Another thing is my question for C++, that link is not much helpful.

Comment: I mean putting a sub-pattern inside parentheses `(...)`. The Nth group can be accessed as `sm[N]`.

Comment: Ah yes I understand, thanks for the clarification. So it seems I have no other choice but to use boost regex, I think it supports named groups.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 regex allows different flavors, which have slightly different features. Regex flavor defaults to ECMAscript [(1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex/basic_regex), which doesn't have named capture groups [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines#Part_2).

You can try using one of the other flavors [(3)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex#Constants).

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Regex's [`match_results`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html) claims it can.

```
const_reference operator[](int n) const;
const_reference operator[](const char_type* n) const;
template <class Traits, class A>
const_reference operator[](const std::basic_string<char_type, Traits, A>& n) const;
template <class charT>
const_reference operator[](const charT* n) const;
template <class charT, class Traits, class A>
const_reference operator[](const std::basic_string<charT, Traits, A>& n) const;
```

> The overloads that accept a string, return a reference to the `sub_match` object representing the character sequence that matched the named sub-expression *n*. In the event that there is no such named sub-expression then returns a `sub_match` object whose `matched` member is false.

---

> Another question I have is, what if PLACE has more than one match?

In this case, you have a couple of options. by default, Boost.Regex will only return the last match. There's [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html) section of boost's documentation that tells you how to enable repeated captures. Another way that might work (depending on regex) is to do something like:

```
string text("abc abd");
regex regex("ab.");
string::const_iterator start=text.cbegin(), stop=text.cend();
match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
while(regex_search(start,stop,results) {
  cout<<string(match[0].first, match[0].second)<<endl;
  start=match[0].second;
}
```